# Special escape character in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a textbox in my application, in this textbox, I want to perform a validation check. If user enter **[, \ .']** these characters, it should prompt message that invalid character. However, what I did is just the regex to check the characters, but it seems that C# have trouble recognize **[\']** these simple. Are there a ways to deal with these special characters?

Comment: Keep in mind that when writing the regex, you have to escape the `'` character in the regex, but you also have to escape the `\ ` for the string itself, so you need to type `"[\\']"` (or `@"[\']"`)

Comment: Please include the code you are using to create the expression.

Comment: It is probably caused by the \. To detect \ you should use double backslash. `\\\` any code from your side would be helpful to check the actual case

Comment: @DragonBorn Could you please change the selected answer as the latter works perfectly. Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are trying to keep only alpha-numeric and space characters. Add a keypress event like this

```
    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
       var regex = new Regex(@"[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]");
       if (regex.IsMatch(e.KeyChar.ToString()))
       {
          e.Handled = true;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
   private static readonly char[] SpecialChars = @"[,.']".ToCharArray();
   int indexOf = YourInputString.IndexOfAny(SpecialChars);
   if (indexOf != -1)
   {
             //Print Contains Invalid Character 

   }
```